# In subdomain only images are not showing , what to do?

Tags: image, .htaccess, subdomain, relative-path

http://www.something.com/m is showing all the images.But in subdomain
http://m.something.com is not showing any images. 
(don't mind about my design)
Everything is fine.Image links are correct.I am puzzled what is happening.Please suggest me .

Is there any problem with my htaccess file.I don't want to put hard coded links ,because there are so many images.
I have also a htaccess file in the root folder(public_html) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^more/([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)? index.php?ln=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^show/([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)? tv.php?tv=$1&&ln=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tv/([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)? show.php?tv=$1&&info=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The subdomain is trying to load images from root of subdomain folder. Show your configurations for the subdomain.

Comment: I am new,what is the configuration ? every other files are working , but what is the problem with image ?

Comment: How is your subdomain set? Where do you define the subdomain to load its pages from?

Comment: I set it from the 'subdomain' option from the server . I set m for m.drissho.com where I have a folder with named 'm' in the server.  every other files are working , but what is the problem with image ?

Comment: Since you tagged the question with htaccess, I thought the server configurations are available to you. If they aren't, go with the answer already provided below (use hard-coded links).

Comment: I have a htaccess file in the root folder(public_html) with coded  below

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^more/([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)? index.php?ln=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^show/([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)? tv.php?tv=$1&&ln=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^tv/([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)? show.php?tv=$1&&info=$2 [L]


is this what you wanted ?

Comment: code added.Please help

Comment: Did the method suggested in my reply helped? If it did, you can select it as answer and this question will not appear in unanswered questions list.

Comment: Sorry , It didn't work. I used the hard url . By the way.. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are trying to render images from the subdomain instead of the main domain. You have uploaded the images to the main domain.

One solution is, in the image tag, use the full URL instead of the relative URL

```
<img src="../vid_photo/85179657faa1d0059ef85ab7f4986d25.png" />
```

Should be

```
<img src="http://www.drissho.com/vid_photo/85179657faa1d0059ef85ab7f4986d25.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference images from subdomain with "../".
You can copy images to your subdomain and use hrefs like in domain app or reference image from subdomain directly with absolute paths to domain like "http://www.drissho.com/images/play.png".